# How do I delay/wait/pause actions?

Tags: c#, action, delay, wait, pause

I have been trying to get a border in my wpf application(c#) to flash red and blue when you input the wrong password.
my code:

```cs
//This method executes when you enter the wrong password
void Alert() 
{
    Count = 0;
    while (Count <= 5)
    {
        Border_.BorderBrush = Brushes.DarkRed;
        //Timer here
        Border_.BorderBrush = Brushes.DarkBlue;
        //Timer here
        Count++;
    }
}
```

I have tried using `await`, `Thread.Sleep(1000)`, `Task.Delay(1000)` and `Timers` but nothing worked. I searched for any similar question but could not find any solution that worked for me. (This question didnt work for me either: [How to create a Flashing and Normal Background Visual States for a Border control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917873/how-to-create-a-flashing-and-normal-background-visual-states-for-a-border-contro))

Answer (score -1):

This is the code-behind example, without visual states;

```
public Task Alert()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        int Count = 0;
        while (Count <= 5)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Border_.BorderBrush = Brushes.DarkRed);
            //Timer here
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Border_.BorderBrush = Brushes.DarkBlue);
            //Timer here
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Count++;
        }
    });
}
```

And you can call with;

```
await Alert();
```

Also, do not forget to set `BorderThickness`.